# how to avoid collision between first and third layer when second is between them? Unity 2D C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, collision-detection, game-physics, game-development

I have 3 layers: **car**, **track** and **outOfTrack** layer. Under **car** and **track** is **outOfTrack** layer. When a **car** is on **track** the collision between **car** and **outOfTrack** is detected, so i want to avoid it somehow.
How to avoid collision detecting between **car** and **outOfTrack** when **car** is on **track**, and detecting it only when car is touching **outOfTrack**?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Edit->ProjectSettings->Physics.
There you have the collision matrix. With the checkboxes you define which layer collides with which.

[image]

Edit: The collision matrix isn't supposed to change all existing contacts in realtime. If we were to do this, we'd have to re-evaluate every single contact in the world which could be very expensive and is easily abused. Check [this](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1325050/after-collision-matrix-change-in-runtime-effects-n-1.html). So you can try to change the collision matrix with code, you can probably do so, however I would suggest to handle the collisions thinking of them in terms of **space**, not **time**.

By this I mean that you try to detect the collision not at the time **when** your car is out of track, but, with the corresponding layers and colliders, detect the collision **where** its out of track.

If you are still into changing the collision matrix in runtime you can try check out the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.IgnoreLayerCollision.html)

Comment: if i disable collision between car and outOfTrack layer then i cant detect when car get out of track.

Comment: handle that with a new layer. Think about the behaviour you want and set the collision matrix accordingly

Comment: @rustyBucketBay thought this as well at first but note that the question is unclear as OP actually doesn't want to ignore any layers really ^^ OP rather wants to only then react to the one layer if the other layer is not currently touched anymore ^^ this requires both layer collisions enabled

Comment: thanks for spotting that out @derHugo . Updating the answer